# Where to find recordings of serious Fate Core campaigns?

Tags: fate-core

**Are there any recordings of serious campaigns played in Fate Core out there?**

By serious I do not disqualify games which contains humour and jokes (can it be even avoided?) but games which were obviously started for comical reasons.

I am specifically looking for video recordings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is actually a [Fate Game Room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/8403) On this site. (Currently locked for inactivity unfortunately) But in it's transcript you will find many discussions about Fate, and some games that were played there.

There is even a transcript of a 1 on 1 game I had introducing me to Fate (using the FAE rules) with BESW; [Part 1](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8403/conversation/sen-the-magnificent-part-0-fae-tutorial-game), [Part 2](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8403/conversation/sen-the-magnificent-part-1-fae-tutorial-game), [Part 3](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8403/conversation/sen-the-magnificent-part-2-fae-tutorial-game), [Part 4](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8403/conversation/sen-the-magnificent-part-3-fae-tutorial-game).

Other than that, there are [many](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5MIdOX4jy9Y) [youtube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kaGnFRuyvto) [videos](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6k5mNsRhre0) that show people playing games (Note: Some of these videos are a bit loose with the rules). It is not hard to find people playing, discussing, or liking Fate -- it's great!.

So unless you were looking for something very specific (which you did not mention in your question) I think you came to the right place!

Comment: I've clarified - I've been thinking about video recordings specifically. Funny that my youtubeing only gave me gazillion of 'how to play' and 'review' videos. My Youtube-fu must be low today.

Comment: I've looked into some of these videos, and some aren't actually following Fate Core's rules - they're still using holdover rules, like the apparently common mistake that you still need to spend a fate point on an aspect in order to use it or let it justify anything. Might be worth making a warning about that.

Comment: @doppelgreener: In the current edition of Fate Core and Fate Accelerated Edition, to "use" an Aspect (*invoke* it), you **do** need to spend a Fate Point, unless through some action you've received a free invocation of that particular aspect (succeed on a Create an Advantage action). I know this comment is a few years old at this point, but clarifying that it seems to no longer be accurate?

Comment: @Midnight We are on the same page there on invokes, but I'm talking about [invoking for effect](http://fate-srd.com/fate-system-toolkit/aspects#invoking-for-effect) which is a removed feature in FC/FA, and very different to a regular invocation. Past editions would say someone with "out of ammo" isn't *actually* out of ammo until that aspect was invoked for effect. Likewise someone's *my grandfather's sword* aspect wouldn't let them do swordy stuff unless they were invoking it for effect... etc.  Nowadays all of that is just automatic. You're out of bullets and you have a sword.